# Does the "type" of a struct change from computer to computer?

Tags: c++, types

Let's assume I have this code;

```
class Ingredients{
    public:
        Ingredients(int size,string name);
        int getsize();
    private:
        string name;
        int size;
};

struct Chain{
    Ingredients* ing;
    Chain* next;  
}
```

And in my main;

```
int main()
{
    cout<<typeid(Chain).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(Chain->ing).name()<<endl;
    cout<<typeid(Chain->next).name()<<endl; 

}
```

my headers are;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
```

and finally outputs;

```
P8Chain
P12Ingredients
P8Chain
```

so my question is, will this types are reliable for using it in a code? If the types are changing (because of the P8 and P12 things I am not sure it would be the same) from computer to comp. this types wouldn't be reliable. What are your opinions?

Also they are *not* changing on every run.

Comment: Once the program is compiled, they won't change. About whether they'd be the same when compiled with different compilers, I can't tell

Comment: The `typeid.name` is not "the type", just a mangled name for it.

Comment: suppose they both are compiled at the same g++, but different computers, Is standard saying something about this?

Comment: There's nothing dictating what the type name looks like, AFAIK.  So, different compilers would produce different results.  A typeid is only really useful when compared with another typeid in the same program.  Two computers that used the same version of the same compiler on the same OS would almost certainly produce the same name for a typeid, but even that isn't really required...

Comment: `Chain->ing` does not compile.

Comment: The standard says nothing about g++, for obvious reasons. The g++ documentation _does_ talk about g++, but if you're interested in that, you shouldn't be asking about the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They depend on your compiler, so don't use them inside your code.

The C++ standard says the following concerning `typeid` ([section 5.2.8](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf)):

> The result of a `typeid` expression is an lvalue of static type `const std::type_info` and dynamic type `const std::type_info` or `const` *name* where *name* is an **implementation-defined class** derived from `std::type_info`.

What you *can* do if you want some sort of [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) is

```
if (typeid(myobject) == typeid(Chain)) {
    do_something();
}
```

Comment: As eran pointed out, the problem is the `type_info::name()` member function (see §18.7.1/9 `type_info::name()`: "_Returns:_ An implementation-defined NTBS"). I heard rumors there's a C++14 proposal to make this portable, but I cannot find it.

Comment: It's actually 18.5.1 that describes the `name` member; 5.2.8 just describes how to get the `type_info` (or compatible) object. Otherwise, this is perfect. In fact, the standard as written makes it perfectly legal to return the empty string for every type's name, which means you can't even rely on it as a programmer-readable description of the type for debugging purposes.

Comment: @abarnert Section 5.2.8 talks about `typeid`. That's what I wrote. Click on the link and you'll see :)

Comment: Yes, `typeid` is how to get the `type_info`. That's exactly what I said. The part of the standard that says that the result of calling `name()` on the `type_info` object is to return "an implementation-defined NTBS" is 18.5.1. (PS, clicking on the link just downloads the whole thing as a PDF, it doesn't display any particular section.)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "type".  The more or less standard definition of type is the set of values and operations the type can take, and this will change from one machine to the next, because the size of `int` will change, or the maximum length of a string.  On the other hand, there is a very real sense that type is what the compiler and the C++ standard consider it to be, which very roughly would correspond to, or at least be identified by the scoped name.  Finally, the `std::type_info::name()` function is seriously underspecified.  At best, it can be useful for debugging (e.g. logging the actual derived class a function was called with), and not all compilers provide even that.  As far as the standard is concerned, a compiler could always return an empty string, and still be conform.

Comment: +1 for explaining that the _type_, as defined literally, actually doesn't change, but the `type_info::name` does. However, I think there's a third thing which is actually more useful than either, which might also be worth calling "type": two types are the same iff a compiler and linker will practically treat them as equivalent (which means the platform-specific name mangling, layout, etc. are all relevant).

Comment: @abarnert That's what was behind what I was saying in "there is a very real sense that type is what the compiler and the C++ consider it to be".  But this really only applies to legal C++.  Violate the one definition rule, and the "undefined behavior" can lead to a lot of confusion with regards to the type.  The names may be mangled the same, but the possible values and operations could be completely different.  (And of course, this definition also means that the definition of type is different in C and in C++.)

Comment: My point is that your implementation's representation of that C++ type may differ from, say, one build to the next, even though the type as defined by the language will not. This is why you can't necessarily link together two C++ files that use the same type—if they were compiled by different compilers, with different settings, etc., it's not the same type in the sense that matters. (And since this can affect things that you are legally allowed to peek at in your code, even perfectly legal and working code, it's not purely theoretical.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the standards the name() is implementation defined (as well as according to Stroustrup book - see p 415 on 3th edition)

Answer (score 1):

The word "type" has multiple meanings.

In terms of type theory, a C++ struct doesn't really define a type at all.

More usefully, the C++ language standard talks about types in a way that can be taken rigorously, even if it never quite rigorously defines the term. In those terms, the struct declaration does define a unique and consistent type.

Maybe even more usefully, to your C++ compiler (and C linker), a type is represented by things like a memory layout, a mangled name, a list of member names and types, pointers to special and normal member functions, possibly pointers to vtable and/or rtti info, etc. This will not be the same from implementation to implementation. Between builds with the same implementation, some details (like where the pointers point) may change even if no relevant code changes, but you could probably define a useful subset of information that you could usefully call a "type" that doesn't change.

Beyond that, the `type_info` instance defined by section 18.5.1 of the standard cannot change within the bounds of what's explicitly defined, and the result of `typeid` as defined by section 5.2.8 as to be that instance or a compatible object that still compares equal to it. So, it sounds to me like, if it were possible to load up the `type_info` instances from two different runs at the same time, `operator==` would have to return `true`. However, it's not actually possible to load up `type_info` instances from two different runs (there's no requirement that they be serializable in any way, for example), so this may not be relevant.

Finally, the name displayed by `typeid().name()`, as defined by section 18.5.1, is just any implementation-defined NTBS. It could change between builds, runs, even calls within the same run. It could always be empty. Practically, it'll often be something vaguely useful for debugging, but that isn't guaranteed—and, even if it were, that wouldn't help, because "vaguely useful for debugging" doesn't have to mean "unique within a run and persistent across runs".

If you're asking about a specific compiler, the documentation for the compiler may give stricter guarantees than the standard requires. For example, I believe that on various platforms g++ guarantees that it'll use the C++ ABI defined at CodeSourcery, and will not change ABI versions within minor compiler versions, and will use the mangled names defined in the ABI as the `type_info` names. This means taking the binary to another computer won't affect the names, and even recompiling the source on another computer with the same platform and g++ version won't affect the names.

Comment: Just a small point where I'm not sure I agree.  In C++ (but not in C), I think a `struct` does define a type, at least potentially.  Part of the definition of a type is the set of operations possible on it.  And if you have functions which take a `T&` or a `T const&`, they are part of the operations possible on it.  (On the other hand, this makes the definition of type somewhat open.  You can add to the operations on it at any time.)

Comment: Type in which terms? I already said that a struct defines a type-as-defined-by-C++ (and you're right, that's not true for C). Are you arguing that it also defines a type-as-defined-by-type-theory? If so, then, as you say, the fact that free functions can extend the type means that the struct can't possibly define a type. And in fact, that's really the whole point behind the "free functions are part of a class's interface" idea.